# Do you only flip the inequality sign when dividing a negative number?

Tags: inequality, arithmetic

Does it happen in multiplication too?

Comment: Multiplication and division are essentially the same thing.  Dividing by $2$ is just multiplying by $\frac{1}{2}$, so yes.

Comment: BTW, welcome to math stackexchange.  You should probably remove the linear-algebra tag since this question has nothing to do with linear algebra.

Comment: $$2<3$$
Do we have $(-1)\cdot2<(-1)\cdot3$ or $(-1)\cdot2>(-1)\cdot3$ ?

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in the comments, multiplication and division are essentially the same thing.  You can do some experimenting as see what "should" happen.  For example:

You know that $2 < 3$.  If I multiply both sides by $-2$ which direction should the inequality go?  $-4 < -6$ or $-4 > -6$?  This would suggest that you should flip the inequality if you multiply by a negative number.

If you want to know why, think about the numbers on a number line.  You say that $2 < 3$ because $2$ is to the left of $3$ on the number line.  When you multiply (or divide) by a negative value, the numbers are reflected over the zero on the number line (and possibly scaled).  For example, multiplying both numbers by $-1$ gives you $-2$ and $-3$.  The result is that the number that was closer to $0$ (the $2$) is still closer to $0$... but it was on the left and is now on the right (because of the reflection).  So the number that was bigger is now smaller--so the inequality flips.

Answer (score 0):

When you have an inequality, for instance $a>b$, and you multiply or divide by a negative number, the inequality "flips" to $-ak<-bk$, where $k$ is the number you multiply by (which is just dividing by $1/k$. One way to think about this is that the greater than sign is measuring "rightness" of numbers - that is, how far right they are on the number line. When you multiply by a positive number you're just stretching or squishing the number line, so which one is farther to the right doesn't change, but when you stretch or squish *and flip it upside down* (multiplying or dividing by a negative number) the one that used to be on the right is now farther to the left, so the inequality sign flips.